# Change redux state without using bindActionCreaters

Tags: redux

I have a simple JavaScript file for example abc.js. I want that when this file runs a state in redux is updated. Is it even possible to perform a task like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update redux state you need to dispatch actions, that will be processed by the reducer.

Please check out this tutorial by Redux creator Dan Abramov: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Should be useful for you to learn more about state, reducers and actions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support.